# Vala - fatal error: gtk/gtk.h - thrown error using Gtk libs

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, vala

Source code in Vala:

```
using GLib;
using Gtk;

class MainWindow : Window  {

  public static int main (string[] args) 
  {    
    var window = new MainWindow();
    window.destroy.connect(Gtk.main_quit);
    window.show_all();

    Gtk.main();

    return 0;
  }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    this.title = "Title";
    this.set_default_size(400, 450);
    this.border_width = 10;

    this.window_position = WindowPosition.CENTER;
    this.destroy.connect(Gtk.main_quit);

    var btnClear = new Button.with_label("Button");
    add(btnClear);
  }
}
```

When compiling on Ubuntu 13.10, I got error:

```
user@dev:/path$ valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 "dev.vala" -o dev
/path/dev.vala.c:7:21: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gtk/gtk.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
error: cc exited with status 256
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

So, Ubuntu uses Gtk3. I've forcd to use gtk3.0 and make sure that libs for libgtk3 installed.

Secound question, If I want to develop Gtk 2.0 how can I do on Ubuntu if supports only Gtk 3?

Comment: Gtk+ 2.0 applications should run fine on Ubuntu, where did you get the idea that they do not? A lot of Gtk+ applications still use 2.0

Comment: Because I got several errors on Ubuntu using terminal and compiling Vala. I've got errors on both version. You need to install libgtk2-dev for compiling from library of gtk2. Maybe because I'm on Xubuntu instead of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the `libgtk-3-dev` package, too.

The `-dev` suffixed packages in Debian and Ubuntu based distros contain files necessary for development.

In addition there is also a `libgtk2-dev` package for Gtk+ 2.0 application development in Ubuntu.

Comment: I've done with this example: http://gdm9000.wordpress.com/2012/07/21/vala/ Works.

Comment: I've seen your profile. I came from Java mostly. What you prefer cross platform language with GUI?

Comment: Personally I'd write a GUI for each platform with the native platform tools and put the logic in a Vala or C shared library. I like to have a native user experience in my apps.

Comment: BTW: You can ask such questions at http://programmers.stackexchange.com and http://ux.stackexchange.com, stackoverflow is more about specific programming issues. Questions about package management really belong to http://www.askubuntu.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com/